# Regex to find value after a specific term

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I want to save any value that appears after a specific string.

The text is as follows:

```
ug=595ad8543534510555d9; ugs=1; s_ppv=54353; optimizelyEndUserId=orwe535908r0.58354354373; countryCode=US; geoData=new york|NY|11432|US|NA; _uetsid=_u5435fgdac3e; _t_tests={"[dasds59ec]":"B","[2fdfsde8cd]":"A","lift_exp":"m"};
```

In the above text, the value for the fields will change for different users. The tag names remain the same. I want to fetch the value of *geoData*. So, everything that comes after *geoData=*.
In the above data, I want to get back :

`new york|NY|11432|US|NA`

I came up with `/geoData=[^;]*/` , however, that gives me `geoData=new york|NY|11432|US|NA`.

How do I exclude the `geoData=` part from my regex to give me just the value after that `=` sign ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should utilize a capture group (wrap the portion you want to keep in parenthesis): `geoData=([^;]*)/`

```js
const match = 'ug=595ad8543534510555d9; ugs=1; s_ppv=54353; optimizelyEndUserId=orwe535908r0.58354354373; countryCode=US; geoData=new york|NY|11432|US|NA; _uetsid=_u5435fgdac3e; _t_tests={"[dasds59ec]":"B","[2fdfsde8cd]":"A","lift_exp":"m"};'.match(/geoData=([^;]*)/);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Or use `replace` method:

```js
var text = 'ug=595ad8543534510555d9; ugs=1; s_ppv=54353; optimizelyEndUserId=orwe535908r0.58354354373; countryCode=US; geoData=new york|NY|11432|US|NA; _uetsid=_u5435fgdac3e; _t_tests={"[dasds59ec]":"B","[2fdfsde8cd]":"A","lift_exp":"m"};'

console.log(
  text.replace(/.*geoData=([^;]+).*/, "$1")
)
```